# What does "got carried off the field" imply or mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, implication

I couldn't get the implication or metaphor of the phrase in the following sentence; is it a slang?

The context is :

Bruce Banner, the Hulk, got under the mind control of Wanda, and he went rogue, causing great damage to the civilians. The whole team is a mess now.

Here is the sentence:

> He was talking to Maria Hill, who was on the dashboard screen. “The
>   news is loving you guys,” she said. “Nobody else is. There’s been no
>   official call for Banner’s arrest, but it’s in the air.”
>
> “The Stark Relief Foundation—” Tony began, but she was ahead of him.
>
> “Already on the scene. How’s the team?”
>
> “Everyone’s . . .” Tony had meant to say something reassuring, but he
>   couldn’t make it happen. “We took a hit. We’ll shake it off.”
>
> “People find out **the Avengers got carried off the field,** there’s going
>   to be panic,” Hill said. “And that’s from the people that like you.”
>
> “Recommendation,” Tony said.
>
> “Stay in stealth mode and stay away from here.”
>
> “So run and hide.”
>
> “Until we can find Ultron,” Hill said, “I don’t have a lot else to offer.”
>
> *The Avengers*

Answer (score 3):

In sporting and military battles, when you are injured you are literally **carried off the field**.  In the example it's not clear whether they were actually injured, or whether the speaker is worried that they might be.

Note that the grammar in your example is a kind of abbreviated style common to spoken military and police.

The following examples have the same meaning.

- Example: **People find out X, there's going to be Y**
- Fuller: **If** people find out X, there's going to be Y
- Fullest: **If** people find out X, **then** there's going to be Y

Comment: I really have no idea that the whole sentence should  be "IF people find out…", so could your explain more? is it a subjunctive ? is this abbreviation quite common in spoken language?

Comment: I elaborated the answer a bit, hope it helps.

Comment: thank you very much:)